# Karma -- [preprocessor.rollup]: Could not resolve '../../services/service.ts'

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, npm, karma-jasmine, bamboo

---

I'm having a testsuite which I'm now trying to test via CI. (Bamboo)

The problem is that this is fully functional on my local system, but wen I deploy it to the Bamboo server (which I cannot configure myself) the call `npm --harmony test` (`--harmony` to use `const` while `use strict`) fails.

Next, it returns the following errormessage

```
07-Oct-2016 16:37:03    07 10 2016 16:37:03.315:ERROR [preprocessor.rollup]: Could not resolve '../../services/apicaller.service' from /opt/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MANCAVE-JOB1/src/pages/events/events.component.ts
07-Oct-2016 16:37:03     at /opt/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MANCAVE-JOB1/config/karma-shim.ts
07-Oct-2016 16:37:03    Error: Could not resolve '../../services/apicaller.service' from /opt/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MANCAVE-JOB1/src/pages/events/events.component.ts
07-Oct-2016 16:37:03        at Error (native)
07-Oct-2016 16:37:03        at /opt/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MANCAVE-JOB1/node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-resolve/dist/rollup-plugin-node-resolve.cjs.js:78:21
07-Oct-2016 16:37:03        at /opt/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MANCAVE-JOB1/node_modules/browser-resolve/index.js:265:24
07-Oct-2016 16:37:03        at /opt/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MANCAVE-JOB1/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:55:18
07-Oct-2016 16:37:03        at load (/opt/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MANCAVE-JOB1/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
07-Oct-2016 16:37:03        at onex (/opt/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MANCAVE-JOB1/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
07-Oct-2016 16:37:03        at /opt/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/MCAE-MANCAVE-JOB1/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
```

where `../../services/apicaller.service` is an import statement in `src/pages/events/events.component`

---

Project structure (minified to match errormessage's scope)

```
src 
|
--config
| |
| --karma.conf.js
| --karma-shim.ts
| --protractor.conf.js
| --rollup.config.js
|
--pages
| |
| --events
|   |
|   --events.component.ts
|
--services
  |
  --APICaller.service.ts
```

---

**Karma.conf.js:**

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const ts = require('rollup-plugin-typescript');
const buble = require('rollup-plugin-buble');
const nodeResolve = require('rollup-plugin-node-resolve');
const angular = require('rollup-plugin-angular');
const commonjs = require('rollup-plugin-commonjs');
const alias = require('rollup-plugin-alias');

module.exports = function karmaConfig(config) {
    var configuration = {
        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (e.g. files, exclude)
        basePath: '../',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
            require('karma-rollup-plugin')
        ],
        reporters: [
            // // Reference: https://github.com/mlex/karma-spec-reporter
            // // Set reporter to print detailed results to console
            // 'spec',
            // // Reference: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage
            // // Output code coverage files
            // 'coverage'
            'progress'
        ],
        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser we are building
        // the config environment in ./karma-shim.js
        files: [
            'config/karma-shim.ts'
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            'config/karma-shim.ts': ['rollup']
        },
        rollupPreprocessor: {
            context: 'this',
            plugins: [
                angular({
                    exclude: 'node_modules/**'
                }),
                ts({
                    typescript: require('../node_modules/typescript')
                }),
                alias({
                    '@angular/core/testing': path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/@angular/core/testing/index.js'),
                    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing/index.js'),
                    '@angular/compiler/testing': path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/@angular/compiler/testing/index.js'),
                    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/testing/index.js')
                }),
                commonjs(),
                nodeResolve({ jsnext: true, main: true, browser: true }),
                buble()
            ]
        },
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
         // Continuous Integration mode if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: true
    };

    // if(process.env.GITLAB_CI){
    //     //configuration.browsers = ['Chrome_travis_ci'];
    // }

    config.set(configuration);
};
```

---

**Karma-shim.ts**

```
    declare var __karma__: any;

    __karma__.loaded = () => { };

    import 'core-js/client/shim';
    import 'reflect-metadata';
    import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
    import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
    import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
    import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
    import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
    import 'zone.js/dist/proxy';
    import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';

    import 'rxjs/Rx';

    import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
        BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
        platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
    );

    import '../src/pages/home/home.spec';
    import '../src/pages/events/events.spec';
    import '../src/pages/event-detail/event-detail.spec';

    __karma__.start();
```

---

**rollup.config.js**

```
const rollupConfig = require('../node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/rollup.config');
const replace = require('rollup-plugin-replace');

console.log('Editing default ionic configuration');

const nodeEnv = JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV) || 'development';
const apiUrl = JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL) || '';
const platform = JSON.stringify(process.env.PLATFORM) || 'android';

rollupConfig.plugins.push(replace({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': nodeEnv,
    'process.env.API_URL': apiUrl,
    'process.env.PLATFORM': platform
}));

module.exports = rollupConfig;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that Bamboo is case-sensitive. And since my `APICaller` doesn't follow the angular's `kebab-case`, Bamboo couldn't find the path.

Class was `APICaller.service.ts` and import was `{..} from 'apicaller.service`. Change to `{..} from 'APICaller.service` made it work